# How to properly test a NestJS Repository?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

In my NestJS project I am using the repository pattern and postgres as my DB.

I have this `organization.repository.ts` (only showing 2 methods here)

```ts
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException, Logger, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';

import { CreateOrganizationDto } from './dto/create-organization.dto';
import { OrganizationEntity } from './organization.entity';
import { UpdateOrganizationDto } from './dto/update-organization.dto';

@Injectable()
export class OrganizationRepository extends Repository<OrganizationEntity> {
  private readonly logger = new Logger('OrganizationRepository', {
    timestamp: true,
  });

  constructor(dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(OrganizationEntity, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }

  async createOrganization(createOrgDto: CreateOrganizationDto): Promise<OrganizationEntity> {
    const { name, logoUrl, orgType } = createOrgDto;
    const org = this.create({ name, logoUrl, orgType });

    try {
      await this.save(org);
      return org;
    } catch (ex: unknown) {
      const stack = ex instanceof Error ? ex.stack : '';
      const msg = ex instanceof Error ? ex.message : '';

      this.logger.error(`Failed to create organization! Data: ${JSON.stringify(createOrgDto)}`, msg, stack);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }

  async getOrganizationById(id: string): Promise<OrganizationEntity> {
    const found = await this.findOneBy({ id });
    if (!found) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Organization with id '${id}' not found.`);
    }
    return found;
  }
}
```

I need to test the logic in here, which means I will need to mock database responses.  I'm a little lost here, but here's what I have so far.

```ts
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';

import { OrganizationEntity } from './organization.entity';
import { OrganizationRepository } from './organization.repository';
import { OrganizationTypeEnum } from './organization-type.enum';

const mockOrg: OrganizationEntity = {
  id: '1234-5678-90',
  name: 'Foo Company',
  logoUrl: '',
  type: OrganizationTypeEnum.DIRECT,
};

describe('OrganizationRepository', () => {
  const testConnection = 'testConnection';
  let repo: jest.Mocked<OrganizationRepository>;
  let entityRepository: jest.Mocked<Repository<OrganizationEntity>>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const connection = new DataSource({
      type: 'postgres',
      database: ':memory:',
      dropSchema: true,
      entities: [OrganizationEntity],
      synchronize: true,
      logging: false,
      name: testConnection,
    });

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        OrganizationRepository,
        { provide: DataSource, useValue: connection },
      ],
    }).compile();

    repo = module.get(OrganizationRepository);
    entityRepository = jest.mocked(connection.getRepository(OrganizationEntity));
  });

  it('should have the repo mocked', () => {
    expect(typeof entityRepository.find).toBe('function');
  });

  it('should create an organization', async () => {
    //entityRepository.create.mockReturnValue(mockOrg);
    entityRepository.save.mockResolvedValue(mockOrg);

    const result = await repo.createOrganization({
      name: 'foo',
      logoUrl: '',
      type: OrganizationTypeEnum.DIRECT,
    });

    expect(result).resolves.toEqual(mockOrg);
  });

  it('should throw an InternalServerErrorException when creating an organization fails', async () => {
    //entityRepository.create.mockReturnValue(mockOrg);
    entityRepository.save.mockRejectedValue(new Error());

    const result = await repo.createOrganization({
      name: 'foo',
      logoUrl: '',
      type: OrganizationTypeEnum.DIRECT,
    });

    expect(result).rejects.toEqual(new InternalServerErrorException());
  });
});
```

I feel like I'm close here, but not 100% getting it yet. Right now these test will run, but they fail with these errors:

```
TypeError: entityRepository.save.mockResolvedValue is not a function
TypeError: entityRepository.save.mockRejectedValue is not a function
```